# Update Value in a Table using Reactive Forms Method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

It's a bit difficult to give a simple example ...

I have a model and its price displayed and an edit button in a table, when I click on the edit button, a Modal is displayed to modify the price.

In the Modal, there is an Input and a Validate Button, in the Input, the initial Price is displayed. I managed to display the initial price with the Get SetValue method of Reactive Forms.

The problem is that I would like when I modify the price and I validate it, it is displayed in the table which contained the initial price.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem:

[image: Model with it's price]

[image: Edit Option of the Price]

```
HTML Code : 

    <table class="table table-dark mb-3">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Modèles</th>
        <th scope="col">Prix Unitaire ( U )</th>
        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let modele of modeles; let i = index">
      <tr>
        <td>Model {{ modele.idModele }} ( {{ modele.modele }} )</td>
        <td>{{ modele.prix }} €</td>
        <td>
          <a
            class="btn btn-outline-light"
            (click)="editPrixModele(i)"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#modalPrixModele"
          >
            <i class="far fa-edit"></i
          ></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- Modal Edition Prix Model Start -->

  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="modalPrixModele"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalPrixModele">Edition Du Prix :</h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form [formGroup]="prixModeleForm">
            <label for="prixModele">Prix Modele : </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Entrer le Prix : ( € )"
              formControlName="prixModele"
            />
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Fermer
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="validatePrixModele()"
          >
            Enregistrer
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal Edition Prix Model End -->



TS File : 



export class PrixOptionsComponent implements OnInit {
  modeles = [];
  travaux = [];
  batiments = [];
  nbrEtages = [];
  chargeNominale = [];
  nbrPersonnes = [];
  dimensionCabine = [];

  prixModeleForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private prixOptionsService: PrixOptionsService,
    private formbuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.prixOptionsService.getModeles().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.modeles = data;
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log("observable modele success");
      }
    );
    this.initPrixModeleForm();
  }

  initPrixModeleForm() {
    this.prixModeleForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      prixModele: [""],
    });
  }

  editPrixModele(index) {
    console.log(this.modeles[index]);
    this.prixModeleForm.get("prixModele").setValue(this.modeles[index].prix);
  }
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change somes little things:
In HTML, i would pass, the modele itself, instead of the index:

```
<a
   class="btn btn-outline-light"
   (click)="editPrixModele(modele)"
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#modalPrixModele"
  >
    <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
</a>
```

I would keep this modele, into a property editModele:

```
export class PrixOptionsComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  editModele: any = null;
  ...
}
```

So we need to change the editPrixModele function:

```
editPrixModele(modele) {   
  this.editModele = modele;
  this.prixModeleForm.get("prixModele").setValue(this.editModele);

}
```

finally, in the validateForm function:

```
validatePrixModele() {
   // Check here, if value is correct ....

   this.editModele.prix = this.prixModeleForm.value.prixModele;
   this.editModele = null;

   //Close your modal ....

   this.prixModeleForm.reset();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked :) but I have a little problem ... When I validate the new Price, it gave me in the " String " format not in " Number " :)

An other think I want to know please :) You used : 

    this.editModele = null;

What's gonna do this line ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: We keep in a property the modele we re editing, once we validated and finished, we simply remove the modele from property, cuz we are not editing it anymore.
Ofc, in the case, you close the editModal on validation, otherwise, you have to remove this line.
For the number type, simply add type="number" in your input, it will automatically put a number in the formControl, instead of a string.

Comment: Thank for your time and your explanation :) I understand now what you did :) Thank you again :)